# Servlet filter change response?

Tags: java, servlets

I have below servlet filter.

```
public class MyFilter extends BaseServletRequestFilter {

        @Override
    protected void afterExecutingFilterChain(final ServletRequest requset, FilterResponseWrapper response) throws ServletException {

//To do
    }

       @Override
    protected void beforeExecutingFilterChain(final ServletRequest requset, final FilterResponseWrapper response) throws ServletException{

    //Here request needs to be intercepted
   //To do
}


}
```

I have abover filter. My requirement is i need to intercept the request. I need to check some boolean value in the request. If boolean variable is true then request processing should be continued. If boolean variale is false then request should not continue and i need to send some custom response as below.

```
public enum CustomStatus {


    OK("Ok"),

    BAD_REQUEST("BadRequest");

    private final String value;

    CustomStatus(String v) {
        value = v;
    }

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }

    public static CustomStatus fromValue(String v) {
        for (CustomStatus c: CustomStatus.values()) {
            if (c.value.equals(v)) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
    }

}
```

If request boolean variable's value is false then i have to set above custom status into response and return without processing the request. How can i do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Filter interface:

```
public final class XssFilter implements Filter {

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
  throws IOException, ServletException
{
    //check request...
    if (ok) {
       chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
       // do something with the response
    }
}
```

Can't be more specific that that, because you don't say exactly where the boolean value you are checking is (is a parameter, or part of the URL, or a cookie, or a header?), neither do you say exactly what you want done with the response.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can i send my CustomStatus as response?

Comment: Not directly. The response will be a HttpServletResponse, which contains all the info returned to the browser. You can serialize a CustomStatus into the response by using ObjectOutputStream with HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream() but that's quite advanced. It is easier to just set the status, e.g. response.setStatus(403). You can also set some text into in the headers (response.setHeader(name, value)).

Answer (score 2):

If you create a `Filter` by extending [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html), you can do:

```
public void  doFilter(ServletRequest request, 
      ServletResponse response, 
        FilterChain chain)
        if(your status is ok) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(the error code,
                                "the error message" );                          
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i dont want to send any error. can i send custom response as my custom status ? Thanks!

Comment: You can use the `setStatus(int)` method on `HttpServletResponse`

Comment: is there anyway to send my CustomStatus ? Thanks!